# How to use axioms for a proof in axiomatic set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

I am learning set theory and find it confusing sometimes to understand how to use an axiom in order to solve an exercise. My main problem is beginning the proof and understanding how to proceed.

Example:
Let X be a set. Show that { {y} : y ∈ x} is a set.
The way I saw how to solve this question was first to use the power set axiom, and say that {y} (singleton set) is a subset of X. I do not think this is the right way to go about the question and was wondering if anyone could explain/ give advice on how to solve these types of exercises with the axioms in set theory. Also, someone said that using the axiom of separation is actually another way to solve this question?

Thanks!

Comment: @saulspatz Sorry about that! I just edited and put the full question in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axioms tell us the allowed ways to "make"/define new sets from given sets, and here we're just given $x$. This has elements and a set like $\{y\}$ is a subset of $x$ so it is logical to use the power set axiom, and then filter out the singletons. We can use the formula

$$\phi(y):= (\exists z: z \in y) \land \left(\forall z: \forall z': ((z \in y) \land (z' \in y)) \to (z=z')\right)$$

to state that the set $y$ has exactly one element.

Then we know $\mathscr{P}(x)$ is a set and we can justify the existence of your set by the axiom of separation applied to the power set and $\phi$ from above:

$$\{\{y\}: y \in x\} = \{y \in \mathscr{P}(x) \mid \phi(y)\}$$

Alternatively for each set $y$ we can define $\{y\}$ by the pairing axiom applied to $y$ and $y$... and we know from the axiom of extentionality that $\{y\}$ is uniquely defined from $y$. So then we can apply the axiom of replacement with the "class function" $y \to \{y\}$ with domain the given set $x$ to justify that indeed
$\{\{y\}: y \in x\}$ is a set as well.

Afterthought: we could also have used $$\psi(y,x) = \exists z: (z \in x) \land ( y=\{z\})$$

and separation (and also pairing, really) in the first approach. Many ways lead to Rome.

Comment: Afterafterthought: Even $\exists z\colon y=\{z\}$ would be enough as we use separation on $\mathscr P(x)$ anyway

Comment: @Hagen: Except that formally $\{z\}$ is not an expression in the language of set theory.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thank you for clearing that up! In the solution you've written, you use the axiom of separation to define that {y} set is a singleton set. Do I need to define the set/formula first (always?) before I start a proof in set theory? I am having difficulty with constructing new formulas as you did with ().

Comment: @alliknowisiknownutin Whenever you use separation, yes, you need to write the formula. IMO abbreviations like $\{z\}$ are allowed (they are justified by other axioms, but they're stricly not in the "strict" language of set theory with $\in$ and $=$. So as Hagen suggested $\{y \in \mathscr{P}(x) \mid \exists z: y = \{z\}\}$ is also fine by most teachers' standards. So the fomula isn't that hard to write down then.